# PHP mySQL timestamp need return date as 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get time from `TIMESTAMP` using php in mySQL

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $detail["work_time"] = date("H-i-s", strtotime($row["entry_time"]));
}
```

The value of row entry_time is `00:00:00 00:00:00` but when I print `$detail["work_time"]` the result is `01:00:00`. I need the `00:00:00` result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a timezone problem

Comment: What exactly is coming out of `$row["entry_time"]`?

Comment: what is your default time zone

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a36b59aa12a210e33bc89d91f1f2a564eac56ee1 Look at this code. It can help if you add Y-m-d to know what your date is converted to.

Comment: @mathielo its 00:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it. If you have `strtotime()`, you have to put valid string, which is the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

The minimum date is `January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC`. If your timezone is +1, the full time will be `January 1 1970 01:00:00 UTC` by default. 
You can check it: just put `d-m-Y` before `H-i-s`.

You should refactor your logic.

Comment: but wont date month and year will be printed too if i add d-m-y?